# Initializing an atomic flag in a malloc'd structure

Tags: c, struct, atomic, freebsd, c11

I'm trying to use atomics in `C` on FreeBSD 10.1 Release with clang 3.6.1, however when I try to compile a program using `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` on a `atomic_flag` variable in a `struct` I get `error: expected expression`.

Here is the program I am trying to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

struct map
{

    atomic_flag flag;

};

int main(void)
{
    struct map *m = malloc(sizeof(struct map));

    m->flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

    free(m);

    return 0;
}
```

I can use `atomic_flag` outside of `structs` like in the example below but not in `structs`, so how do you use atomic variables in `C` `structs`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

int main(void)
{
    atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: YOu are aware thay `m` is uninitialized?

Comment: Yea, but even initializing the struct you get the same compiler error.

Comment: I should have tagged that as "note". Of course, that does not solve the error. However, what if you create an automatic variable?

Comment: Depending on your usage: you might use `atomic_bool` instead and use `atomic_init`. Not sure if the latter is allowed for `atomic_flag`, too. To me, `atomic_flag` looks more like the essential helper type to implement all other atomic types. IOW: smallest common denominator.

Comment: This is not specific to FreeBSD, nor to clang. Can I suggest changing the title to be a little more generic. Something like "Initializing an atomic flag in a malloc'd structure"?

Comment: @Henry Gomersall Yea your right it would make more sense, I will change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`atomic_flag` doesn't have value that you can assign to or read from, but only an internal state.

The only way to interact with `atomic_flag` are the two functions (or four if you count the `_explicit` versions) that are defined for it. For your case when you got your object through `malloc` the flag is in an "indeterminate state" (7.17.8 p4 of C11). You can simply put it into a known state by applying one of the two functions, that is use `atomic_flag_clear` to set it to the "clear" state, or use `atomic_flag_test_and_set` to set it to the "set" state.

Using `atomic_flag_clear` right after an allocation with `malloc` is
equivalent to an initialization of a variable with `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT`.

Comment: Can you be more thorough?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, when I try to `atomic_flag_clear` after `malloc` it works but not if I mmap the struct as shared memory, it segfaults on the `atomic_flag_clear`.  Im using `struct map *m = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct map), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);`

Comment: Nevermind I'm going to accept this because you answered my question and the last comment is a second question, so I will post a second question, thanks.